# Modulous without division for powers of two

Tags: bit-manipulation

with reference to, [modulous formula](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/mod.shtml)

can someone explain how `a mod m = ( (b mod m)(a/b) + (a mod b) ) mod m` works in case of for powers of two (2^n).

With base 10 the explanation is clear, but unable to do it for base 2 numbers, e.g :-

`9 mod 4 = ( ( 2 mod 4)(9/2) + (9 mod 2) ) mod 4`, how can i deduce it to 9 & (4-1)?

Comment: which number is 2^n ? Where did you get `a mod m =  ...` formula from ? Is this Mersenne numbers?

Comment: @diginoise I have given the link ( http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/mod.shtml ) from where I got this formula

Comment: this is the only formula I have found on that page which is close to yours, but not yours:      `a mod 3 = ( (a/4) + (a mod 4) ) mod 3`. Did you mean this one ?

Comment: the general formula is `a mod m = ( (b mod m)(a/b) + (a mod b) ) mod m` , where b is the base of numbers a and m,  using this author has tried to explain how we deduce divisibility by 2,4 ,3, 9 etc in decimal (base 10) numbers, he says the formula can be used with any  numbers from all bases.

Comment: I just want to understand how we can use this formula for binary numbers (base 2)